# Cannot set inner property of null

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to make an app that will help me with my workouts and help me constantly lift more so that I can get stronger. I keep getting the error "Cannot set inner property of null" on the very bottom when I try to output the variables to the HTML. It's the code under the last section of comments that I am getting the error. Can some give me some guidance on how to fix this?

```
//Get the variables from the user. This will be the previous exercise or the exercise that the       user has performed
const userSet = document.getElementById("set-user-1");
const userReps = document.getElementById("reps-user-1");
const userWeight = document.getElementById("weight-user-1");
var futureSet;
var futureReps;
var futureWeight;

//Define the functions that need to be done between the previous exercise and the next exercise
function getNewSet(previousSet) {
    return previousSet;
}

function getNewRep(previousReps){
    if(previousReps < 12) {
        return previousReps + 2;

    } else {
        previousReps = 6;
        return previousReps;
    }
}

function getNewWeight(previousReps, previousWeight) {
    if(previousReps < 12){
        return previousWeight;
    } else {
        previousWeight = previousWeight + 10;
        return previousWeight;
    }
}

//Make a function that runs all the functions with the user input
function getNewWorkout() {

    futureSet = getNewSet(parseInt(userSet));
    futureReps = getNewRep(parseInt(userReps));
    futureWeight = getNewWeight(parseInt(userReps, userWeight));

    return futureSet;
    return futureReps;
    return futureWeight;
}

//Output will go to the future exercise dividers
document.getElementById("future-sets").innerHTML = futureSet;
document.getElementById("future-reps").innerHTML = futureReps;
document.getElementById("future-weight").innerHTML = futureWeight;
```

Comment: Are you sure the DOM is ready when you run that code?

Comment: where is this script located? it wont work if its in the `<head>`

Comment: You are not calling the function in this script. I can't tell what is happening with your app but you have to set the futureSet, futureReps and futureWeight somewhere. Now they are indeed null as you are not setting them. And I don't get the downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the last two lines of this function. A function can only return one value, it might be worth putting all the values in an array
and then returning it.

```
//Make a function that runs all the functions with the user input
   function getNewWorkout() {
        futureSet = getNewSet(parseInt(userSet));
        futureReps = getNewRep(parseInt(userReps));
        futureWeight = getNewWeight(parseInt(userReps, userWeight));

        return futureSet;
        //error here
        return futureReps;
        return futureWeight;
   }
```

So you can update your code as follows to return object,

```
function getNewWorkout() {
        const futureSet = getNewSet(parseInt(userSet));
        const futureReps = getNewRep(parseInt(userReps));
        const futureWeight = getNewWeight(parseInt(userReps, userWeight));
        return {futureSet, futureReps, futureWeight};
   }
```

Which you can access through object.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error comes when you load the script before DOM is ready. You can try to load the script at the end of the HTML, usually in footer. This should fix your error.

Also, please call the function 'getNewWorkout()' in your script to get expected output.